# Is it possible to do a partial Wifi Scan on Android?

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifimanager

I want to non-selectively be able to receive a subset of all Wifi routers' information in range of the Android device. However, in the WifiManager API I only see the getScanResults() method returning List (the results of the latest access point scan). Is there a way to get a subset of this list at the expense of smaller scan time?

Comment: Maybe I could do a scan on a specific channel?

Comment: Checked out android "iw" library, it requires the user to root the device, but it does enable specific channel/frequency scanning.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such APIs in [WifiManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html)